# Update list with the results of different threads in Kotlin

Tags: multithreading, list, kotlin, thread-safety, mutablelist

I want to update a list with the result of different threads.

```
mainFunction(): List<A> {
  var x: List<A> = listOf<A>()
  val job = ArrayList<Job>()
  val ans = mainScope.async {
            var i = 0
            for (j in (0..5)) {
                job.add(
                    launch {
                        val res = async {
                            func1()
                        }
                        x += res.await()
                    }
                )
            }
         job.joinAll()
        }
  ans.await()
  return x
}
fun func1(): List<A> {
 //Perform some operation to get list abc
 var abc: List<A> = listOf<A>()
 delay(1000)
 return abc
}
```

The list "x" is not getting updated properly.
Sometimes, it appends the "res".. sometimes it does not.
Is there a thread-safe way to modify lists like this?

New implementation:

```
mainFunction(): List<A> {
 var x: List<A> = listOf<A>()
 val ans = mainScope.async {
   List(6) {
     async{
      func1()
     }
   }.awaitAll()
 }
 print(ans)
 for (item in ans) {
  x+= item as List<A> // item is of type Kotlin.Unit
 }
}
```

Comment: you should be able to use `Collections.synchronizedList` from Java and create a thread-safe mutable list from that. You can read the docs of it to see how it works.

Comment: This kind of seems like an XY-problem. What are you actually trying to do? Do you want to perform N tasks concurrently, and get all the results in a list at the end?

Comment: @Alex.T Shouldn't really use synchronization in conjunction with Kotlin coroutines I think.

Comment: About the edit, could you please share the code of `func1()`? It looks like it's not returning what you think. If `func1` returns a `List<A>`, `ans` should also be a `List<A>` so you shouldn't have to cast anything (also you can't cast `Unit` into `A` or `List<A>` anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short answer

Here is a simpler version of what you're doing, which avoids the synchronization problems you might be running into:

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    return coroutineScope {
        List(6) { async { func1() } }.awaitAll()
    }
}
```

You can read the long answer if you want to unpack this. I will explain the different things in the original code that are not really idiomatic and could be replaced.

#### Long answer

There are multiple non-idiomatic things in the code in the question, so I'll try to address each of them.

##### Indexed for loop for 0-based range

If you just want to repeat an operation several times, it's simpler to just use [repeat(6)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html) instead of `for (j in 0..5)`. It's easier to read, especially when you don't need the index variable:

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    var x: List<A> = listOf<A>()
    val job = ArrayList<Job>()
    val ans = mainScope.async {
        repeat(6) {
            job.add(
                launch {
                    val res = async {
                        func1()
                    }
                    x += res.await()
                }
            )
        }
        job.joinAll()
    }
    ans.await()
    return x
}
```

##### Creating lists with a loop

If what you want is to create a list out of that loop, you can also use `List(size) { computeElement() }` instead of `repeat` (or `for`), which makes use of the [List factory function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html):

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    var x: List<A> = listOf<A>()
    val ans = mainScope.async {
        val jobs = List(6) {
            launch {
                val res = async {
                    func1()
                }
                x += res.await()
            }
        }
        jobs.joinAll()
    }
    ans.await()
    return x
}
```

##### Extra async

There is no need to wrap your launches here with an extra async, you can just use your scope on the `launch`es directly:

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    var x: List<A> = listOf<A>()
    val jobs = List(6) {
        mainScope.launch {
            val res = async {
                func1()
            }
            x += res.await()
        }
    }
    jobs.joinAll()
    return x
}
```

##### async + immediate await

Using `async { someFun() }` and then immediately `await`-ing this `Deferred` result is equivalent to just calling `someFun()` directly (unless you're using a different scope or context, which you aren't doing here for the inner most logic).

So you can replace the inner-most part:

```kotlin
val res = async {
    func1()
}
x += res.await()
```

By just `x += func1()`, which gives:

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    var x: List<A> = listOf<A>()
    val jobs = List(6) {
        mainScope.launch {
            x += func1()
        }
    }
    jobs.joinAll()
    return x
}
```

##### launch vs async

If you want results, it is usually more practical to use `async` instead of `launch`. When you use `launch`, you have to store the result somewhere manually (which makes you run into synchronization problems like you have now). With `async`, you get a `Deferred<T>` value which you can then `await()`, and when you have a list of `Deferred` there is no synchronization issues when you [await them all](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html).

So the general idea of the previous code is bad practice and might bite you because it requires manual synchronization. You can replace it by:

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    val deferredValues = List(6) {
        mainScope.async {
            func1()
        }
    }
    val x = deferredValues.awaitAll()
    return x
}
```

Or simpler:

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    return List(6) {
        mainScope.async {
            func1()
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

##### Manual joins vs coroutineScope

It is usually a smell to `join()` jobs manually. If you want to wait for some coroutines to finish, it is more idiomatic to launch all those coroutines within [a `coroutineScope { ... }` block](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html), which will suspend until all child coroutines finish.

Here we have already replaced all `launch` that we `join()` with `async` calls that we `await`, so this doesn't really apply anymore, because we still need to `await()` the deferred values in order to get the results. However, since we are in a suspend function already, we can still use `coroutineScope` instead of an external scope like `mainScope` to ensure that we don't leak any coroutines:

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    return coroutineScope {
        List(6) { async { func1() } }.awaitAll()
    }
}
```

Comment: That last point on the join  call is new to me. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Joffrey Your solution seems to be returning an aggregate list to me. For information, `func1()` returns a list ( List<E>). `x` is supposed to be an aggregate list of all the lists returned by the function (List<E>). 
In you solution, `x` is a list of `<Kotlin.Unit>` : `[kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit]` when I am printing it as `print(x.toString())` How do I convert them to a readable format of List<E>?

Comment: @Saakshi no, `x` is not a list of `Unit`. `x` is a list of whatever is returned by `func1()`. For instance, if `func1()` returns 42, you get `[42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42]` (https://pl.kotl.in/kfI4f7zpX). Now you had not mentioned that `func1()` returned lists itself, and that you wanted a flattened list (there is no way to tell from the initial code). In this case, my current solution would return a list of lists (still not a list of `Unit`). You can simply use `.flatten()` on it to have a flat list of elements (https://pl.kotl.in/0xWyoddnb).

Comment: @Saakshi could you please share the exact code you're using when you get `Unit`? If you add stuff within the `async` after the `func1()` call, you will get that stuff instead of `func1()`'s value. For instance, if you add a log call (returning `Unit`), you will get a list of `Unit`.

Comment: @Joffrey I appended the list returned `func1()` within `async` and that worked. Thank you for the solution. 
Regarding, Kotlin. Util:
```suspend fun mainFunction(): List<A> {
    val x =  coroutineScope {
        List(6) { async { func1() } }.awaitAll()
    }
print(x.toString())
}```
Here, `[kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit, kotlin.Unit]` is printed.

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works, but I'd like to understand why/how you're getting those `Unit` results. Did you check my playground links? They do print stuff that are not `Unit`, so could you please provide a playground showing the `Unit` result while using a `func1` that returns a `List` as you said it does?

Comment: I am facing another issue now. func1() performs some activity that takes around 1-2 seconds. To replicate that, I have set a `delay(1200)` in `func1()`. As I had mentioned, I am appending the list returned by func1() to my main list within async. After applying this delay, the list is not getting appended. Can you help me understand why this may be happening?

Comment: Please edit the question with the actual code of `func1`, or the delay you use to mimic it. Also, I'm not sure I understand what solution you picked eventually, but it feels like you're still using the shared mutable state approach we're trying to avoid by using `async`'s  return value. Please share the code of the new solution (either in a new question, or an edit to this question.

Comment: @Joffrey 
I have edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: @Saakshi Please provide your implementation of `func1` as well (even your fake one calling `delay`). The only possibility for your list to contain `Unit`, is if that function is returning unit.

Comment: I was storing the value outside of coroutine scope, which was returning Unit (which holds "nothing"). On straight away using the value of `list`, i could capture the value i needed. Thank you for the solution

Comment: Be careful that some functions like `async` and `coroutineScope` return a value based on whatever is the last expression in the lambda, so if you add `println()` or logging at the end of such blocks you will get `Unit`. It's important to share exactly the code you're using so we can help you with this stuff. It would be interesting if you shared your final successful attempt (maybe with a playground link), because I have a feeling you're still manually copying stuff into another list, which is unnecessary

Comment: @Joffrey Just wondering about the performance aspect of this process of making a list by executing `someFunction` asynchronously. I have tested a simple operation like making a list of a particular size by calling for example `List(100) { 42 } by using coroutines(https://pl.kotl.in/ZA3HA8b1S) and also just a normal synchronous way(https://pl.kotl.in/kgyte4DsQ). It turns out that the latter is much faster. So Would the coroutine way be suitable for other complicated cases rather than what OP is trying to do?

Comment: @roksui 1) [microbenchmarks like this have no value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1540818), please use JMH to measure the correct thing. 2) making things concurrent has a non-zero cost (task management, thread synchronization if parallel, etc.). It is only worth parallelizing if what you're doing in parallel takes significant time. This is not only for coroutines, but in general. 3) Here you're using `runBlocking` so things are only concurrent but not parallel. Also, every operation is literally just reading a constant, so you'll have no benefit at all, and only additional cost.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to perform some tasks concurrently and get a list of all the finished results at the end, you could do this:

```
val jobs = (0..5).map { mainScope.async { func1() } }
val results = jobs.awaitAll()
```

Comment: SInce this requires to be in a `suspend` function anyway due to `awaitAll()`, I would suggest using `coroutineScope` instead of an external scope.

Comment: @Joffrey Good point.

Comment: Thank you. How do I parse "results"? 
Unable to read my custom object values that are returned by func1().

Comment: @Saakshi what do you mean by "parse"? `results` is a list of 6 values, all of which are the results of repeated calls to `func1()`

Comment: @Joffrey results is a list of Kotlin.Unit objects since coroutines return Unit objects. I want to parse them/case them to my custom object but i am unable to.

Comment: @Saakshi So `func1` returns `Unit`? `Unit` contains no information. The list will be filled with whatever the `func1` function returns.

Comment: @Saakshi coroutines don't necessarily return Unit objects. Using `async` like in this answer allows you to get a result from `func1`. If `func1` returns something useful, you will get it.